# How are DTOs serialized automatically while transferring them over the network (java)

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, jax-rs, dto

I have few DTOs (in frontend) and each one of them implements Serializable interface.

My question is that how  are DTOs automatically serialized when I send DTOs over the network to my another remote application (say backend)? My Remote application has a web service (jax-rs) method which accepts that DTO.

I know that in order to serialize any object we have to write some piece of code.

But in this case, I am not writing any code to serialize my DTO while transferring and de-serialize it when it is received by my remote application.

I am  using spring boot with jax-rs-jersery in my backend project.

Thanks!

Comment: That's something done by the framework. If you still want more knowledge, consider going through source code of the one you use.

Comment: In general an [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) is used to serialize Serializable objects and an [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) is used to deserialize them. The exact moment the [writeObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject-java.lang.Object-) and [readObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject--) operations are called will depend on your framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of framework is going to have some point of conversion. For JAX-RS, it's the [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html). To handle the serialization, the [`writeTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html#writeTo-T-java.lang.Class-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap-java.io.OutputStream-) method is called

```
void writeTo(T t,
         Class<?> type,
         Type genericType,
         Annotation[] annotations,
         MediaType mediaType,
         MultivaluedMap<String,Object> httpHeaders,
         OutputStream entityStream)
  throws IOException,
         WebApplicationException
```

The object `t` is passed to the method along with the entity stream for the response. It's up to the implementor to convert this object to a steam to bytes.

There a bunch of different writers, and one chosen depends on the media type, the object type, and possible other factors determined in the [`isWriteable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html#isWriteable-java.lang.Class-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-) method.

You can read more about entity providers in the [Jersey docs chapters 8 and 9](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html).